# Order by id is slow

Tags: performance, query-performance, mysql-5.5

So I've read the same issues here that people experience, I could find at least a few topics talking about how ORDER BY is slow.

However, it looks like I have all the indexes necessary. But still with ORDER BY id, it takes about 1.5 seconds to complete the query, when I remove ORDER BY id part it runs crazy fast, like 0.020 seconds.

Here's the query I'm running:

```
SELECT `companies`.*
FROM (`companies`)
JOIN `companies` as CP ON `CP`.`parent_id` = `companies`.`id`
JOIN `categories_companies` ON `categories_companies`.`company_id` = `CP`.`id`
WHERE `categories_companies`.`category_id` =  '{NUMBER}'
AND `categories_companies`.`category_id` IS NOT NULL
AND `CP`.`deleted` =  0
AND `companies`.`top_level` =  1
AND `companies`.`deleted` =  0
ORDER BY `id` desc
LIMIT 0, 30
```

As I noted removing ORDER BY `id` desc this query runs fast.

As you can see in the query there are two tables, companies and categories_companies
In companies table there are around 300k records (I'm not making up the numbers, it's quite accurate).
Also categories_companies have almost the same number of records.

companies - Structure

```
id        | int(11)      | NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY
system_id | int(11)      | NULL,
city_id   | int(11)      | NOT NULL,
parent_id | int(11)      | NULL
name      | varchar(300) | NOT NULL,
...other not important fields, like hpone, code, address and such.
```

categories_companies - Structure

```
id          | int(11) |  NOT NULL, AUTO_INCREMENT, PRIMARY KEY
company_id  | int(11) |  NOT NULL
category_id | int(11) |  NOT NULL
description | text    |  NOT NULL, utf8_lithuanian_ci
```

Running explain gives me this:

```
1 | SIMPLE | categories_companies | ref  | category_id,company_id,company_category category_id | 4 | const | 157562 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
1 | SIMPLE | CP                   |eq_ref| PRIMARY,parent_id,deleted | PRIMARY | 4 | database.categories_companies.company_id | 1 | Using where
1 | SIMPLE | companies eq_ref     | PRIMARY,toplevel,deleted,top_level_deleted,top_lev... | PRIMARY | 4 | database.CP.parent_id | 1 |  Using where
```

I see that using 'filesort' could be a problem, but how do I improve this? I've never dealt with quite a large amount of rows, so optimizations are rare. But would be glad if you could give me any tips on what I could try to make it run faster, or using ORDER BY id is lost cause in this case? I'm not very knowledgeable about indexes and optimizing queries in general, so while still learning it all looks like playing a game to me since I can't draw my own correct conclusions yet, about what may be wrong.

Any help is really appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure about the mysql-5.5?

Comment: Yes, what is uncommon?

Comment: An up-to-date version of MySQL might use the index for an order by descending.

Comment: BTW, do you have indices on company.parent_id and categories_companies.company_id ?

Comment: Yes, I did:
„ALTER TABLE `companies` ADD INDEX(`parent_id`); AND
„ALTER TABLE `categories_companies` ADD INDEX(`company_id`); 
But it does nothing. Yeah definitely order by id is the problem if I remove it runs very fast. 

Server version: 5.5.37 - MySQL Community Server (GPL)

Comment: Then you need to upgrade.  Don't stop at 5.7 and you might as well go for MariaDB.

Comment: Thank you I'll try to set up the newest MySQL version, import the tables with data there, and see how it goes. Do you think there is an issue with old version not being able to order results fast?

Comment: There was a lot to improve on MySQL 5.5, and on MySQL itself. That's why there were new releases and even MariaDB. Still, I always preferred PostgreSQL (when I compared both MySQL didn't have foreign keys yet).  Do the upgrade in a test environment with a copy of the production data.